# How can i pass same append element data as an array to the controller with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#addmatches').click(function(e){
    var count=$('#countmatches').val();
    var test = "<?php echo form_error('match_teamone');?>";

    if (count==0){
        $('.count #noofmatches').addClass('has-error');
        $('.count .erroraddmatch').show();
        $('.count .erroraddmatch').text('The field is required');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{

        for (i=1;i<=count; i++){

            $('#panel_body').append('<div class="panel panel-default" id="match_panel">'+
                    '<div class="panel-heading headingchange">'+
                        '<h3 class="panel-title">'+i+'. Match</h3>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="panel-body">'+
                        '<div class="col-md-5 match_teamone">'+
                            '<select name="match_teamone" class="form-control first_select" id="match-teamone"></select>'+

                        '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label>VS</label>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-5 match_teamtwo">'+
                        '<select name="match_teamtwo" class="form-control second_select" id="match-teamtwo"></select>'+

                    '</div>'+
                    '<br><hr>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-5 match_ground">'+
                        '<select name="match_ground" class="form-control" id="match-ground">'+
                            '<option value="">--- Select Ground ---</option>'+
                            '<option value="tribhuwan">Tribhuwan University Ground</option>'+
                            '<option value="2016">Mulpani Internation Ground</option>'+
                            '<option value="2017">Pulchok Engineering Ground</option>'+
                            '<option value="2018">Bhaktapur Ground</option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2 match_time">'+
                        '<select name="match_time" class="form-control" id="match-time">'+
                            '<option value="">Time</option>'+
                            '<option value="2015">00:00 AM</option>'+
                            '<option value="2016">00:15 AM</option>'+
                            '<option value="2016">00:30 AM</option>'+
                            '<option value="2016">00:45 AM</option>'+
                            '<option value="2016">01:00 AM</option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-5 match_umpire">'+
                        '<select name="match_umpire" class="form-control" id="match-umpire">'+
                            '<option value="">--- Select Umpire ---</option>'+
                            '<option value="2015">Mohammad Ashqiue Ali</option> '+
                            '<option value="2016">Nischal Tiwari</option>'+
                            '<option value="2017">Razesh KC</option>'+
                            '<option value="2018">Raazan Bhattarai</option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>');

            $('.count #countmatches').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#addmatches').attr('disabled','disabled');   
            $('#match-tournament').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.count #noofmatches').removeClass('has-error');
            $('.count .erroraddmatch').hide();
            e.preventDefault();

        }           
    }
});
```

});

The append is working fine and while i my form submit code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#match').validate({

    rules:{

        match_tournament: {
            required:true
        },
        match_teamone:{
            required:true
        },
        match_teamtwo:{
            required:true
        },
        match_ground:{
            required:true
        },
        match_time:{
            required:true
        },
        match_umpire:{
            required:true
        },
    },

    messages: {
                match_teamone: "Team One should be selected",
                match_teamtwo: "Team Two should be selected.",
                match_ground:"Ground should be selected.",
                match_time:"Time should be selected.",
                match_umpire:"Umpire should be selected.",
            },

     submitHandler: function() {

            var data = $('#match').serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'matches/addMatches',
                    data:$.param(data),
                    success: function(return_data) {
                         alert(return_data);
                    }
                });

            }
});
```

});

My problem is that when i append two panel-body then only last values of panel-body is passed through the jquery but i need both append values to the database.

I changed my name of the appended field with [i] but it make more complex because it create each field an array rather i need all data as in a single array.

Only one appended data is passing to the database i know i am lacking here with array but i am stuck for using array while sending through jquery and load it on to the controller.

Any help will be appreciated . Thank You

Comment: ID must be unique. Change to class definition for multiple element that share the same name. Then find all values and store inside array object to send data

Comment: Change your first line of `append` and add `i` to it -> `.append('<div class="panel panel-default" id="match_panel_'+i+'">'`

Comment: @norlihazmey: how can i do that .. can you give an example

Comment: @guruprasad: if i add i on the begging what that it happens ??

Comment: `Id`'s will be unique for each element!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ok i have added .. but nothing working how can i add to the array ... those values

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali please can you show me an example i am really in need to work this out

Comment: Is `#match` your `form id`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87451/discussion-between-mohmmad-ali-and-guruprasad-rao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this :

```
$('#panel_body')
```

into  this :

```
$('.panel_body')
```

then inside `submitHandler: function()` block put this :

```
var arrayValue = [];

$(".panel_body").each(function () {
  var obj = {};
  $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });      
  arrayValue.push(obj);  
});

// arrayValue suppose to be like this :
// [
//   { match_teamone : "some value", match_teamtwo : "some value",...},
//   { match_teamone : "some value", match_teamtwo : "some value",...},
//   ...
// ]  

$.ajax({
   url: 'matches/addMatches',
   type : 'POST',
   data:{
    myData : arrayValue
   },
   success: function(return_data) {
         alert(return_data);
   }
});
```

Then inside controller just treat `myData` as like array.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/3entt0ea/5/)**

Comment: Thanx let me try once this

Comment: If  `$(".panel_body")` did't work, change into `$(".panel-body")` instead. This line of code to iterate over parent body first before searching for form input. Seems like using  `$(".panel-body")` is more accurate. It would be nice if you can share HTML snippet.

Comment: @MohmmadAli : see demo attached, and browse for console if you're using chrome.

Comment: From the demo page you meant?

Comment: did't get it, where you put console.log, and there is something wrong with parent selector. Can you share HTML snippet, then easy for me to see the whole pictures what we are working on.

Comment: Ok finally i got the value but it is giving me a value that i dont want also .. how can i restict on that and .. while  how can i get this values on controlles ....any syntax would be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87465/discussion-between-mohmmad-ali-and-norlihazmey-ghazali).